# What is |tag| in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking at a rails-project and trying to understand this code:

```
tags.each { |tag| markup << tag(:meta, tag) }
```

The part `markup << tag(:meta, tag)` adds an item to the array markup with the content of `tag`.  but what does `|tag|` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|tag|` represents an element of the `tags` array.

The `each` operator returns all elements of an array or a hash. Inside its block, you execute code for each element in `tags`, and each element is passed to the block as a variable `tag`.

Answer (score 0):

`|tag|` allows you to assign a name of `tag` to each item in the collection `tags` so you can use it within the block

You can put anything there, it would be equivalent to:
`tags.each { |x| markup << tag(:meta, x) }`